# Question on connected and locally connected geometric morphisms.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Is the property of a geometric morphism being both connected and locally connected (in the sense of Part C of the Elephant) stable under pullbacks? I know local connectedness is, I am not sure about connectedness. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 3.3.15 in Part C says that connected *and* locally connected geometric morphisms are stable under pullback (along bounded geometric morphisms), and Example 3.3.17 says that connected geometric morphisms need not be stable under pullback (along bounded geometric morphisms).